# Sorting dates from a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, date

If I have dates such as 23/05/2011, 17/03/2012, 01/07/2010 etc. in a string array is it possible to sort the years first then months then days instead of it sorting the days first?

Comment: if they are in a string array they are strings (not Dates) because string arrays hold...well, you know

Comment: Yes, but first you should ask yourself if the string array should be a string array instead of a DateTime array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could parse them to `DateTime` first:

```
var orderedByDateTime = strings
    .Select(s => new { s, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", null) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.dt)
    .Select(x => x.s);
```